# type checking for conditional expression

Tags: dart

In the following code:

```
main() {
   print('Starting....');
   int x = 10;
   int y = x > 3 ? 'aaa' : 7;
   print(y);
}
```

This is the output:

```
Starting....
Unhandled exception:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
#0      main (file:///tmp/main.dart:4:12)
#1      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
#2      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

why isn't there a compile time error on the assignment to y? Why only runtime error?

version: Dart VM version: 2.8.4 (stable) (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean why **isn't** there a compile time error?

Comment: I think that is a bug. Should have thrown a compilation error.[Github improvements discussion](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25565)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that Dart does still try to make implicit type casts as default behavior. So in this case, Dart will automatically assume you can cast the `String` into a `int`. This behavior can be disabled and will also be disabled by default when non-nullable types are supported:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks

You can add the following to `analysis_options.yaml` (I do also recommend to add `implicit-dynamic: false` but this is not necessary for this specific issue):

```yaml
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
```

And you will then get an error from the analyzer:

```
Analyzing bin/stackoverflow.dart...
  error • A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'. • bin/stackoverflow.dart:4:11 • invalid_assignment
1 error found.
```

The reason why the error are saying `Object` is because Dart has analyzed `x > 3 ? 'aaa' : 7` into the return type of `Object` since that is the only thing in common for `int` and `String`.

Comment: For the record, Dart does not assume that `String` is assignable to `int`. This is a combination of the type of `e1 ? e2 : e3` being the least upper bound of the types of `e2` and `e3`, and the least upper bound of `int` and `sting ` is `Object` (as you say), and then that implicit downcast from `Object` to `int` is allowed. The latter will be fixed with null safety.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to parse the string 'aaa' in a type called int. 'aaa' is not a number so error.

```
String y = x > 3 ? 'aaa' : '7';
```

or do:

```
int y = x > 3 ? 2 : 7;
```

Comment: I believe the OP understands the error. They want to know why it's not caught at compile time, instead of only at runtime like it is now.